# How to mock useRouter in NextJS13 for cypress testing

Tags: next.js, cypress, next.js13

I have a Form :

```
const Form = ({ data }: { data: BuildingAPIResponseData }) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  const { push } = useRouter() // the issue comes from this
  // other code
}
```

My testing:

```
import { Provider } from "react-redux"

import { store } from "@/redux/store"

import Form from "."
import MockRouter from "../../../../../../cypress/mocks/next-router"
import { BuildingAPIResponseData } from "../../types"

describe("Building Details IForm", () => {
  const zipCode = "63110"
  const city = "Rodgau"
  const street = "Liebigstraße"
  const houseNumber = "2"

  const API = `my_api`
  const apiKey = Cypress.env("api_key")

  const data: BuildingAPIResponseData = {
    buildingType: "Ein-/Mehrfamilienhaus",
    familyHome: false,
    constructionYearClass: "1949",
    fullStoreys: 2,
    hasPV: false,
    livingSpace: 137.0,
    roofType: "Flat Roof",
    hasLivingFunction: true,
  }

  it("should make successful request", () => {
    cy.request({
      url: API,
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key": apiKey,
      },
    }).then((response) => {
      expect(response.body[0]).to.have.property("buildingType", data.buildingType)
      expect(response.body[0]).to.have.property("familyHome", data.familyHome ? "True" : "False")
      expect(response.body[0]).to.have.property("hasPV", data.hasPV)
      expect(response.body[0]).to.have.property("fullStoreys", data.fullStoreys)
      expect(response.body[0]).to.have.property("livingSpace", data.livingSpace)
      expect(response.body[0]).to.have.property("roofType", data.roofType)
      expect(response.body[0]).to.have.property("hasLivingFunction", data.hasLivingFunction)
    })
  })

  it("should fill the form with the default data", () => {
    cy.mount(
      <Provider store={store}>
      
          <Form data={data} />
    
      </Provider>
    )
  })
})
```

Issue:

[image]

I tried to use `cypress.stub()` but I got the same error:

```
 beforeEach(() => {
    const pathname = "http://localhost:3000/11127569/energy-check/building-details/summary"
    const push = cy.stub()
    cy.stub(NextRouter, "useRouter").returns({ pathname, push })
  })
```

Answer (score 5):

There is an example in the Cypress docs [React Router](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/component-testing/react/examples#React-Router) that shows a simple way to add the Router to the Component test by wrapping the tested component in a Router provider.

```js
import { mount } from 'cypress/react'
import { MemoryRouter } from 'react-router-dom'

Cypress.Commands.add('mount', (component, options = {}) => {
  const { routerProps = { initialEntries: ['/'] }, ...mountOptions } = options

  const wrapped = <MemoryRouter {...routerProps}>{component}</MemoryRouter>

  return mount(wrapped, mountOptions)
})
```

This is a ***React component test***. If you specifically want to test Next, that compiles to server + client so you would be better testing via e2e instead of component.

Comment: I'm not using React Router.

Comment: Yes e2e testing is straight forward for this.